# Table "Only X Left" on product page doesn't show product names (only Qty) in Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: product, configurable-product, stock, ce-1.9.1.0, stock-status

The issue is also described on Magento Bug-track (still not answered):
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/443

#### Steps to reproduce:

I have created a configurable product consisting of 3 Simple products (hidden individually) with different Stock quantities. When looking at the frontend and having the option: "Only X left" displayed, the quantity is correct. When I expand to display the details, the table is displayed but **does not contain the names of the individual Simple products**. I have tested this with a clean install of 1.9.0.1 which works correctly I have tested this with a clean install of 1.9.1.0 and the information is missing.

#### Expected Result:

Only X left table in the frontend with a breakdown of the Name of the Simple products per row and the Qty of that product in the column behind it Actual Result: Only X left table in the frontend consists of the correct amount of rows and columns. The name column does not display the product name, the Qty column displays the correct information.

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

#### This is how it looks like in Magento 1.9.1.0:

[image]

#### And this is how it should look like (from Magento 1.9.0.1):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that they changed `getUsedProducts` method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable` class.

Magento 1.9.0.1

```
$collection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
```

Magento 1.9.1.0

```
$collection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)
    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

// Provides a mechanism for attaching additional attributes to the children of configurable products
// Will primarily have affect on the configurable product view page
$childAttributes = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_PRODUCT_CONFIGURABLE_CHILD_ATTRIBUTES);

if ($childAttributes) {
    $childAttributes = $childAttributes->asArray();
    $childAttributes = array_keys($childAttributes);

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect($childAttributes);
}
```

So instead of selecting all the attributes they provided a mechanism for us to select only what we need.

```
const XML_PATH_PRODUCT_CONFIGURABLE_CHILD_ATTRIBUTES = 'frontend/product/configurable/child/attributes';
```

So in your module `config.xml` add following:

```
<frontend>
    <product>
        <configurable>
            <child>
                <attributes>
                    <name/>
                </attributes>
            </child>
        </configurable>
    </product>
</frontend>
```

Flush cache, reload product page and enjoy :-)

Comment: So does it mean that Magento team just forgot to add that attribute ("name") in Catalog module's _config.xml_?

Comment: Probably :) I guess no one had that feature in mind.